# Best way to clean up a PDF without increasing file size massively

Tags: windows-7, pdf, disk-space, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-paint

I scan a lot of A4 notes that I write up, but a lot of my old ones have staple holes in them. Some of these scans also have slight imperfections such as a small dot (dirt) on them, which really bugs me when I read through these PDFs.

I have attempted to get rid of staple holes through redaction since the staple holes are always in the same area and I can just apply the same redaction to multiple pages. However this has the unfortunate result of increasing the PDF file size by 7 fold!

Similarly, when I attempt to remove specks of dirt manually by editing the PDF page in paint, the files size also increases dramatically at about 2MB per edited page.

Is there a better way to go about what I'm doing?

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/sample_5) is an example of a page of such a PDF. On this page I would like to remove some of the dirt specks on the actual page, the staple holes on the top left, the hole punched holes on the left, and the black bar on the top right.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of these PDFs and describe the flaw you wish to remove for that PDF?

Comment: @Ouroborus Sure, I've just edited it into the bottom of the post.

Comment: How do you edit a PDF in Paint? Paint only supports image formats, not PDF.

Comment: @DonaldDuck For me it's just right click > edit with > paint. Since these are scans they are very much image formats with uneditable text (if the handwriting is sufficiently neat there is searchability to some extent).

Comment: @IrregularUser Normally, if you do that with a PDF, Paint says `(file path) Paint can't read this file. This file isn't a valid bitmap file, or its format isn't supported`, even if there is only an image in the PDF, that's at least what it does to me.

Comment: @DonaldDuck There is some setting up that you need to do beforehand to get it to open in paint. Try preferences > content editing > image editor then find and choose paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [CleanPDF](https://mega.nz/#!fwYnEToI!FIa4F6e2zelJDMZ1VpAJoSxOViOVPMjfAgMPprnCwSI) (9 MB)

I've put together a small PowerShell script called *CleanPDF* to batch remove certain areas from PDF pages. No additional programs need to be installed. It's a portable solution

The user has to set up a proper mask image to tell the program which areas should be removed. Use Paint.net, Gimp, Photoshop or whatever you have to edit the *mask.png* and preserve transparency

---

### PowerShell Script

```cs
# user variables
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$pdfimages = "$scriptDir\pdfimages.exe"
$convert   = "$scriptDir\convert.exe"
$composite = "$scriptDir\composite.exe"
$mask      = "$scriptDir\mask.png"
$temp      = "$enc:temp\cleanPDF"

# function to remove certain areas from each PDF site according to mask.png
function cleanPDF($file){

    # check if temp folder exists. Maybe from a previous run. If yes, delete it
    if (Test-Path $temp){ Remove-Item $temp -Force -Recurse}
    
    # Create a new temp folder which is always empty
    New-Item $temp -ItemType Dir | Out-Null
    
    # Extract one JPG per PDF site and save them in temp folder
    & $pdfimages '-j' $file.FullName "$temp\image"
    
    # Iterate through each new image and process them
    Get-ChildItem "$temp\image-*.jpg" | foreach { 
             
        # Remove unwanted areas from current JPG with the help of mask.png. Convert JPG to PNG to preserve transparency
        & $composite -compose dst-out "$mask" $_.Fullname -matte "$temp\$($_.BaseName)_result.png"

        # Convert PNG back to JPG so we can replace transparent with white areas. Without this JPG>PNG>JPG trick they would be black
        & $convert "$temp\$($_.BaseName)_result.png" -background white -alpha remove "$temp\$($_.BaseName)_result.jpg"
    }       

    # combine all images back to a single pdf and append "_result" to the file name
    & $convert "$temp\image*_result.jpg" "$($file.Directory)/$($file.BaseName)_result.pdf"

    # Remove temp folder and work images
    Remove-Item $temp -Force -Recurse
}

# Iterate through each passed commandline argument
ForEach ($path in $args){

    # Get path as Powershell item
    $file = Get-Item $path

    # If file extension is .pdf, start CleanPDF function for this pdf
    If ($file.Extension.ToLower() -eq '.pdf') { cleanPDF $file }
}
```

---

### Used tools and techniques

The script uses the following third party tools to handle different tasks

- **pdfimages.exe** (provided within the [Xpdf project](https://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html)) to extract all PDF pages as separate images. But why use pdfimages when imagemagick is also capable of converting PDF files to images? The advantage of pdfimages is that we don't need to install GhostScript

  ```
    pdfimages.exe -j C:\inputfile.pdf C:\outputfolder
  ```
- **composite.exe** (provided within the [imagemagick project](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)) to mask out certain predefined areas

  ```
    composite.exe -compose dst-out C:\mask.png C:\input1.jpg -matte C:\output2.png
  ```
- **convert.exe** (provided within the [imagemagick project](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)) to convert transparent areas to white areas. And to combine all processed images back to a single PDF

  ```
    convert.exe C:\input2.png -background white -alpha remove C:\output3.jpg
  ```

```
    convert.exe C:\input*.jpg C:\output.pdf
```

---

### How to use

1. Download [this .zip file](https://mega.nz/#!fwYnEToI!FIa4F6e2zelJDMZ1VpAJoSxOViOVPMjfAgMPprnCwSI) and extract it to a folder of your choice. You can ignore the warning *The site ahead contains harmful programs* from Google Safe Browsing

The .zip file contains all necessary files so you don't need to download the  imagemagick package (155 MB) or Xpdf package (11 MB)

> cleanPDF.ps1
> convert.exe
> composite.exe
> pdfimages.exe
> mask.png
> sample.pdf

2. Open your sendto folder (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> » shell:sendto) and create a new shortcut. Name it CleanPDF and enter as target location the following path, but change `D:\dir` to your own folder where you extracted the files to

   ```
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "D:\dir\cleanPDF.ps1"
   ```
3. Open `mask.png` and change it to your needs. All non-transparent regions mark the areas which will be removed (masked out). Transparency must be preserved
4. Right click any PDF and choose *Send to » CleanPDF*. A new PDF will be created at the same location

[image]

---

The OPs [sample](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_5). Notice which parts are now removed:

```
sample.pdf (1,35 MB)                sample_result.pdf (1,46 MB)
```

[image] [image]

Comment: This looks AMAZING. One thing - could you upload it to another site? I'm having a lot of trouble with downloads not even starting in firefox/chrome/ie over there for some reason.

Comment: @IrregularUser Changed link from ge.tt to mega.nz. Please try again